# Angular grid showing intermittent bug

Tags: angularjs

Im using version `4.0.2`.

So I configure the grid with this:

```
scope.gridOptions = {
        virtualizationThreshold: scope.pagination.pageSize,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
        enablePaginationControls: false,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableFullRowSelection: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        filterOptions: scope.filter,
        noTabInterference:true,
        columnDefs: [ 
            { displayName: 'ID', name: 'id', field: 'id', type: 'number', sort: { direction: 'asc', priority: 0 } },
            { displayName: 'Name', name: 'name', field: 'name' },
```

By default it sorts ASC on ID and the icon is a triangle with edge pointing above. 
When I click on the sorting-icon for the ID it sorts DESC on ID and the icon is a triangle with edge pointing below. 
The thirth time I click it doesn't sort at all. And the icons appear both but are grayed out.

Inside this function:

```
gridApi.core.on.sortChanged(scope, function (grid, sortColumns) {
    console.log(sortColumns);
```

I see an object the first time I click. But the second time it has an empty array.

What's the point? How is this supposed to work? I would prefer it sorted either ASC or DESC. Removing the alternative to not sorting at all. But I cannot find any parameter for this. It sghould be a parameter in the config above I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of use for sort in angular grid. Are you changing gridOptions.data correct ?

```js
$scope.sortChanged = function ( grid, sortColumns ) {

            console.log(grid);

            var data = $gridCtrl.getData("dataAll");
            if( sortColumns.length === 0 || sortColumns[0].name !== $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].name ){
                $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
            } else {
                switch( sortColumns[0].sort.direction ) {
                    case uiGridConstants.ASC:
                        $scope.gridOptions.data = sortAsc(data);
                        break;
                    case uiGridConstants.DESC:
                        $scope.gridOptions.data = sortDesc(data);
                        break;
                    case undefined:
                        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

gridApi.core.on.sortChanged( $scope, $scope.sortChanged );
```